# how to update soap response namespace value with wso2 ei

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service to expose a soap api on wso2 ei, and i need to update the namespace value of the soap response with my proxy service and return another namespace value.
I have tried with the enrich mediator as follows inside the outsequence.

```
<property name="namespace"
               scope="default"
               type="STRING"
               value="http://tempuri-updated.org/"/>
      <enrich>
        <source clone="false" property="namespace" type="property"/>
        <target xmlns:ser="http://services.samples"
                xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                xpath="namespace-uri($body/*)/text()"/>
     </enrich>
```

I get this error.

> ERROR - EnrichMediator Invalid Target object to be enrich.

my actual soap response is as follows

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <AddResult>12</AddResult>
      </AddResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

my expected output as follows

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri-updated.org/">
         <AddResult>12</AddResult>
      </AddResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

All your feedbacks are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with the enrich mediator. Because in the code related to enrich mediator target handling [[1]](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/elementary/Target.java#L112), the parsed result of an xpath expression should be one of SOAPHeaderImpl, OMElement, OMText or OMAttribute. Since namespace-uri() is just returning a string value, the target to be enriched is becoming invalid. As an alternative to this use case, we can do an XSLT transformation using the XSLT mediator. Following is a sample XSL style sheet I tried.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@* | comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"
             namespace="http://tempuri-updated.org/">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

We can refer this style sheet in the XSLT mediator before sending the response out from the EI. The new namespace will be added to the body.

Comment: its working fine, thank you very much @Thishani Lucas

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

http://codertechblog.com/wso2-change-payload-soap-envelope-namespace/

```
<sequence name="seTestChangeNamespace" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
(...)
<enrich>
<source type="body"/>
<target type="property" property="INPUT_MESSAGE"/>
</enrich>
<enrich>
<source type="inline">
<myns:Envelope xmlns:myns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<myns:Body/>
</myns:Envelope>
</source>
<target type="envelope"/>
</enrich>
<enrich>
<source type="property" property="INPUT_MESSAGE"/>
<target type="body"/>
</enrich>
(...)
</sequence>
```

Comment: This will change the envelope namespace, and retains the body. The namespace that needs to be changed however is in the body.

Comment: Yes, it's not the exact answer. You can modify it to get what you want done.